How to implement TLS for Rust file transfer project
I'm developing a Rust file transfer project, it is just a library to transfer files from device to device, it now works with just TCP but I want to implement TLS encryption for secure connections between the client and server. However, I'm struggling to get it working properly.
Right now, the server starts up, but when the client attempts to connect, the TLS handshake fails, and I can't pinpoint the issue.
I want to set up TLS correctly for this project, including certificate generation, configuring Rustls, and debugging handshake errors.
What I have tried:

Generated self-signed certificates using OpenSSL.
Configured Rustls with the generated certificates.
Verified the certificates are being loaded correctly in both client and server.
Simplified the TLS configuration to troubleshoot, but the issue persists.

Goals:

Secure the connection between the client and server with TLS.
Work in a p2p connection
Ensure certificates are properly configured and verified.
Cross Platform, it needs to work in all devices and connect between diffent os

I am using rustls and tokio_rustls for now but if changing to another library is better it would not be a problem.
I share here the code for client connection and the server.
Client:
pub struct Client {
    client_storage_path: String,
    server_address: IpAddr,
    timeout: Option<Duration>,
    connection: Arc<Mutex<Option<TlsStream<TcpStream>>>>,  
}

impl Client {
    pub fn new(client_storage_path: &str, server_address: IpAddr) -> Self {
        Self {
            client_storage_path: client_storage_path.to_owned(),
            server_address,
            timeout: None,
            connection: Arc::new(Mutex::new(None))
        }
    }

    /// Sets a timeout duration for the client.
    pub fn set_timeout(&mut self, timeout: Duration) {
        self.timeout = Some(timeout);
    }

    /// Connects to the server.
    pub async fn connect(&mut self) -> Result<(), anyhow::Error> {

        let crypto_provider = tokio_rustls::rustls::crypto::aws_lc_rs::default_provider();

        if let Err(err) = crypto_provider.install_default() {
            eprintln!("Failed to install default CryptoProvider: {:?}", err)
        }

        let cert = rcgen::generate_simple_self_signed(vec![self.server_address.to_string()]).unwrap();
        println!("Server Certificate:\n{}", cert.key_pair.serialize_pem());
        let mut trusted = RootCertStore::empty();
        trusted.add(cert.cert.der().clone()).unwrap();
        let connector: TlsConnector = TlsConnector::from(Arc::new(
            ClientConfig::builder()
                .with_root_certificates(trusted)
                .with_no_client_auth(),
        ));
        
        let addr = SocketAddr::new(self.server_address, 8080);

        let tcp = TcpStream::connect(addr).await?;

        let tls = connector
            .connect(ServerName::IpAddress(self.server_address.into()), tcp)
            .await.expect("Could not connect with tls");

        let mut connection =  self.connection.lock().await;
        *connection = Some(tokio_rustls::TlsStream::Client(tls));

        Ok(())
    }
}


Server:
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Server {
    /// Indicates if the server is currently running.
    pub is_server_running: Arc<Mutex<bool>>,
    /// The IP address on which the server listens.
    pub ip: IpAddr,
    /// The port on which the server listens.
    pub port: u16,
    /// The path to the directory where files are stored.
    pub path: String,
    /// Buffer size for file transfer operations.
    pub buffer_size: u64,
    /// Notification signal for stopping the server.
    pub stop_signal: Arc<Notify>,
}

impl Server {
    /// Creates a new instance of the `Server`.
    ///
    /// # Parameters
    ///
    /// - `ip`: IP address on which the server will listen.
    /// - `port`: Port on which the server will listen.
    /// - `path`: Directory path for file storage and retrieval.
    /// - `buffer_size`: Size of the buffer used for file transfers.
    pub fn new(ip: IpAddr, port: u16, path: &str, buffer_size: u64, stop_signal: Arc<Notify>) -> Self {
        let is_server_running = Arc::new(Mutex::new(false));
        Self {
            is_server_running,
            ip,
            port,
            path: path.to_owned(),
            buffer_size,
            stop_signal,
        }
    }

    /// Starts the server, accepting and handling incoming connections.
    pub async fn start_server(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {

        let crypto_provider = rustls::crypto::ring::default_provider();

        if let Err(err) = crypto_provider.install_default() {
            eprintln!("Failed to install default CryptoProvider: {:?}", err)
        }

        let listener = TcpListener::bind(SocketAddr::new(self.ip.to_owned(), self.port)).await?;

        let cert = rcgen::generate_simple_self_signed(vec![self.ip.to_string()])
        .map_err(|e| format!("Certificate generation failed: {:?}", e))?;
        println!("Server Certificate:\n{}", cert.key_pair.serialize_pem());

        println!("Server running on {}", self.ip);
        // accept connection
        let acceptor = TlsAcceptor::from(Arc::new(
            rustls::ServerConfig::builder()
                .with_no_client_auth()
                .with_single_cert(
                    vec![cert.cert.der().clone()],
                    PrivateKeyDer::Pkcs8(
                        PrivatePkcs8KeyDer::from_pem_slice(cert.key_pair.serialize_pem().as_bytes())
                            .unwrap(),
                    ),
                )
                .unwrap(),
        ));

        loop {
            tokio::select! {
                // Wait for an incoming connection
                result = listener.accept() => {
                    match result {
                        Ok((socket, addr)) => {
                            

                            let tls = acceptor.accept(socket).await.unwrap();
                            println!("New connection from: {}", addr);
                            let stop_signal_clone = Arc::clone(&self.stop_signal);
                            let self_clone = self.clone();
                            tokio::spawn(async {
                                if let Err(e) = self_clone.handle_request(tokio_rustls::TlsStream::Server(tls), stop_signal_clone).await {
                                    eprintln!("Error handling connection: {:?}", e);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        Err(e) => {
                            eprintln!("Failed to accept connection: {:?}", e);
                        }
                    }
                },
                _ = self.stop_signal.notified() => {
                    println!("Stopping server...");
                    break;
                },
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}


In case my answer doesn't reflect the only problem, knowing the error message (or other incorrect behavior) might be helpful!

Editor's note: if a link to a repo must be supplied to show all the necessary files, then by definition the question is off-topic. I have thus removed that, plus some requests for general advice, as they could cause the question to be closed. You'll find it easier to get help here if you ask one question at a time, and each question is highly focused on just one thing.

Your code generates1 a random certificate for the server and then an unrelated random certificate for the client. For the TLS handshake to succeed, the certificates must match directly (self-signed) or indirectly (CA signature chain). Try generating a random certificate once and then passing it, as a parameter, to both the server and the client.
1rcgen::generate_simple_self_signed

I see the problem, I will try to figure out how to share that CA between client and server and then I will keep you updated if it worked out.
